Jupyter Notebook : File not reading/writing
I have used both '/' and '//' but neither works. This seems to be the problem despite the file being present in the folder!
`
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[60], line 1
----> 1 with open('Desktop//extra//Hello.txt','r') as f:
      2     content =f.read
      3 print(content)
`
`File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:324, in _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
    317 if file in {0, 1, 2}:
    318     raise ValueError(
    319         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    320         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    321         "you can use builtins' open."
    322     )
--> 324 return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)`

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop//extra//Hello.txt'``



The path appears to be relative. Try using either the explicit (full) path (preferred); or the path relative to the current directory. Also, use a single forward slash.

Additionally, you’ll need to read the file by calling the read function as: content = f.read().  Note the parenthesis. Otherwise content is essentially being assigned as an alias of the read function, without the function ever being executed.

i have tried full path as well as the path relative to current directory. It seems to be an access issue as Error is saying to use buildit functions. I tried running it as a Administration but that doesnt work

Routing the filepath via : ' C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\extra\NewHello.txt' made it work i.e. Folder has to be in the Admin folder!!!
